# MYSQL table, table_tr SELECT default lang WHEN translation not available

Tags: mysql, sql, database, left-join, inner-join

desperately looking for solution. I have basic table and translation table and need select with join but when there is no translation for row -> select default lang translation.

I have table `products` & `products_tr`.

**products**:

```
+----+-------+---------+-------------+
| id | stock | visible | category_id |
+----+-------+---------+-------------+
| 10 | 5     | 1       | 1           |
| 1  | 0     | 1       | 2           |
| 5  | 2     | 1       | 2           |
+----+-------+---------+-------------+
```

**products_tr**:

```
+------------+------+------------+
| product_id | lang | name       |
+------------+------+------------+
| 10         | en   | Blue car   |
| 10         | es   | Carro azul |
| 1          | en   | Red car    |
| 5          | en   | Yellow car |
+------------+------+------------+
```

Need:

- when select lang `'en'` => will return rows with `'en'` translation
- when select lang `'es'` => will return rows with `'es'` if possible for row, if not => return `'en'`.

Thanks.

Comment: Rougly, `SELECT name,lang FROM products_tr WHERE product_id=10 AND lang IN ('es','en') ORDER BY lang="es" DESC LIMIT 1`. In this query
`lang='es'` is a 1 or 0 so pick the es first.

Comment: Thanks danblack, also possible solution. It's a bit complicated when selecting whole table => need this as subquery.

Comment: Yeh, its much more a single value query. Anyway, the JOIN accepted answer is quite good for full table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to `JOIN` the translation table twice:

```
SELECT p.*, COALESCE(t1.name, t2.name) name
FROM products p
LEFT  JOIN products_tr t1 ON t1.product_id = p.id AND t1.lang = 'es'
INNER JOIN products_tr t2 ON t2.product_id = p.id AND t1.lang = 'en'
```

The `LEFT JOIN` *tries to* bring in the record corresponding to the `es` translation, while the `INNER JOIN` selects the default value. Then the `COALESCE()` call returns the `es` translation if available, else the default.

Comment: Amazing, thanks! You're my hero.